# If I disable a script before, can the methods of this object subscribed to an event of a different class be invoked if I call the event later?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, game-engine

I have written a class that is responsible for making an interactive tutorial, I have a Text variable that is the text that shows the steps of the tutorial, but when the player loses and has not finished the tutorial, I want the gameobjet of the text to be deactivated. ()

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.Collections;

 public class TutorialHandler : MonoSingleton<TutorialHandler> , IObserver {

    public Toggle toggleTutorial;
    public Text tutorialText;
    public bool isInitialized;
    public float waitTime;
    private Combo combo;

   //delegate to wait for conditions to continue with the tutorial
    private System.Func<bool> onDeterminacion;

    //variable of the ui class that is responsible for determining whether or not to show the 
    //tutorial
    private UiHandler uiHandler;

    protected override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();

    }
    private void Start() {

        uiHandler = UiHandler.current;

        // toggleTutorial.isOn = uiHandler.showTutorial;
         toggleTutorial.onValueChanged.AddListener((value) => 
        {
            print(value);
            uiHandler.showTutorial = value;

        }
        );
        GameSceneController.current.observers.Add(this);
        GameSceneController.current.otherObservers.Add(this);

        // enabled = false;
        EventBroker.onHitPlayer = DieText;

    }
    private void OnEnable()
    {

    }
    public IEnumerator TutorialManager()
    {
        tutorialText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        if (isInitialized)
        {
            tutorialText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            yield break;
        }
        isInitialized = true;

        //Lineas 
        tutorialText.text = "Dibuja Lineas para jugar!";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        tutorialText.text = "Solo puedes tener 2 lineas disponibles";
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        onDeterminacion += Obstacles;

        while (uiHandler.showTutorial)
        {
            if(tutorialText != null)
            tutorialText.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            yield return new WaitUntil(onDeterminacion);

            if (tutorialText != null)
            tutorialText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        enabled = false;
        isInitialized = false;
        onDeterminacion = null;
    }

     //method subscribed to onHitPlayer
     void DieText()
     {
       tutorialText.gameObject.SetActive(false); 

      }
     //much code here 
   ....
    //methods of iObserver interface
    public void Notify()
    {
        tutorialText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        enabled = false;
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        tutorialText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        enabled  = true;
    }
}
```

I have used the logic of subscribing the DieText () method to an event that is called once the player loses, and this same class implements an interface called "IObserver" with two methods Notify () and Restart (). in another class I keep "tutorialHandler" in a list so I can call the interface methods in a for loop.

```
public List<IObserver> observers = new List<IObserver>();
public void NotifyObservers()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < observers.Count; i++)
        {
            observers[i].Notify();
        }

    }
```

this is the EventBrokerClass.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class EventBroker
{
    public static event Action onHitPlayer; //event called when the player loses

    public static void ExecuteoOnHitPlayerEvent(Player p)
    {
        if (onHitPlayer != null && !Player.isDoublePlayer)
        {
            PersistentData.Guardar(UiHandler.current);
            GameSceneController.current.NotifyObservers(); //I notified the objects IObserver
            onHitPlayer(); //call the event
        }
        else
        {
            p.Die();
        }
    }
}
```

the order of execution first is that I call the for loop of the Iobserver list and then I call the onHitPlayer event.

but it seems that when I deactivated the script previously the methods that I had subscribed are not called. (sorry, no native speaker here :))

Comment: Did you try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) your code with breakpoints? The only thing that is not called anymore if a component is disabled are built-in messages like e.g. `Start`, `Update`, `FixedUpdate` any Coroutine (`IEnumerator`) ... events and any method calls shouldn't be affected at all.

Comment: Yes, I have set breakpoints, but the truth is that it has no effect, I have not managed to find out what happens. it seems that the references of the methods of this class that I have subscribed to the onHitPlayer event are lost

Comment: well where did you set you breakpoints? I would e.g. set one on `if (onHitPlayer != null && !Player.isDoublePlayer)` and see what values these variables have and if there is anything in the action. Then later check if your `observers` list is correct etc

Comment: I did it, I realized that I had unsubscribed the methods in another class. Thank you